# Как написать счетчик посещений?

Tags: сессия, javascript, php, sql

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос. Хочу сделать статистику посещений сайта. В `БД` будут заноситься `user_id`, `session_id`, разрешение экрана, инфо браузера, время прихода, длительность и версия `ОС`. Плюс внизу счетчик посещений уникальных пользователей. Как эот можно осуществить?

Comment: Пишите понятней. Будет толк. Я вот не понял что вам надо и с каким это д.б. функционалом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело-то в принципе не хитрое, это как собственный велосипед :-)

Собственно в самой странице:

```
<div style="width:0;height:0;font-size:0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write('<img src="/counter.php?x='+Math.random()
            +"&u="+escape(window.location.href||document.URL)
            +"&r="+escape(document.referrer)
            +((typeof screen=="undefined")?"":"&y="+screen.width+"x"+screen.height)
            +'" />'
        );
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <img src="/counter.php" />
    </noscript>
</div>
```

Сам счетчик counter.php

```
<?php
    if (session_start()) {
        $session_id = session_id();
        if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
            $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
        }
    }
    if (isset($_SERVER)) {
        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) {
            $user_agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
        }
        if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) {
            $url = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
        }
    }
    if (isset($_GET)) {
        if (isset($_GET["y"])) {
            $resolution = $_GET["y"];
        }
        if (isset($_GET["u"]) and !isset($url)) {
            $url = $_GET["u"];
        }
        if (isset($_GET["r"])) {
            $referer = $_GET["r"];
        }
    }
    // и так далее

    header ("Content-Type: image/gif");
    header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");      // Date in the past
    header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");    // HTTP/1.1
    header ("Pragma: no-cache");                            // HTTP/1.0
    readfile ("/1x1.gif");
```

Comment: Метод `escape` лучше уже не использовать, так-как, он был удален из стандартов и помечен `@Deprecated` - устаревшим. На замену встали `encodeURI, encodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 2):

Не навязываю своё мнение, но через куки всё же проще реализовать и в коей мере лучше.Стоит взвесить все за и против.

Пришёл пользователь проверяем, стоит ли у него наша кука, если не стоит, то -> ставим куку с нужными параметрами -> добавляем в нужную ячейку БД +1.И так по кругу.

Мелкое замечание на счёт заголовков:

```
 header ("Content-Type: image/gif");
 header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");      // Date in the past
 header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");    // HTTP/1.1
 header ("Pragma: no-cache");                            // HTTP/1.0
```

1) **header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");**
Данный заголовок уже наверное вошёл в стандарт.**Это дата добавления!**Там даже так написано :) Однако копипастом его берут себе в код не зная зачем.Как известно, посылать можно любые заголовки, так вот, автор одного зарубежного скрипта, добавил этот заголовок в свой скрипт когда его писал!Вы понимаете сколько ему лет? :) Этот заголовок даже на вики попал.Вообще он не нужен.А если хотите, поставьте настоящую дату: **header("Expires: " . date('r'));**

2) На сколько я понял у Вас в коде написан запрет на кеширование.Самое главное нужно написать: **header("Cache-Control: no-store")**!Это нужно для того, чтобы не сохранять приватные данные.Данный заголовк показывает, что контент является **закрытым=приватным** и его нельзя кешировать!А уже для более универсальной версии можно: **header("Cache-Control: no-store, *no-cahe, must-revalidate*");**